# response of the post method is empty

Tags: angular, ionic3

I'm developing an ionic app which is connected to the server. I'm calling a post method from the app. I'm receiving empty JSON file. but when I tried from the postman I'm getting the expected response.

```
addLocation(coordinates) {
console.log(coordinates)
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.http.post(this.localurl + '/location', JSON.stringify(coordinates), {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json'),
  })
    .subscribe(res => {
      resolve(res);


    }, (err) => {
      console.log("rejected");
      reject(err);
    });
});
```

}
from this method, I'm sending the location of the user to the server. then it has to receive the nearby shops. but I'm receiving empty JSON file. but I'm getting the expected response from the postman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `toPromise` to convert an observable to a promise.

```
addLocation(coordinates) {
  console.log(coordinates)
  return this.http.post(this.localurl + '/location', JSON.stringify(coordinates), {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json'),
  })
  .toPromise()
});
```

Now call it from the component.

```
yourService.addLocation(coordinates).then((res => { 
   console.log(res) 
}, (err) => {
   console.log("rejected"); 
})
```

Comment: I used the toPromise method. But the same result "length: 0__proto__: Array(0)"